# Can we run any post install script after deploying source code to an Org using Salesforce CLI

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm deploying the source code using sfdx force:mdapi:deploy command. Is there a way to specify to execute any post-install script after the deployment gets completed.
One alternative I was thinking of is to use force:apex:execute command to execute post-install activities after the deployment success in the automation script. Please let me if there is an easier way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Post install scripts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script.htm) are available for managed packages. There isn't a post install script function for generic Metadata API deploys.

`sfdx force:apex:execute` is a perfectly acceptable way to run Apex from a script, but be aware that it is fundamentally an Execute Anonymous operation. This means it's subject to all of the usual transaction limits, *plus* the unusual features of Execute Anonymous, such as [enforcing FLS and CRUD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm):

> Unlike classes and triggers, anonymous blocks execute as the current user and can fail to compile if the code violates the user's object- and field-level permissions.

That doesn't mean you cannot or should not use it; you simply need to be aware of its capabilities and unique limitations.